# How do I remove the @yahoo.com from the list and sort it?

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

//This is the email list
var emailList =["adam@yahoo.edu\n", "henry@yahoo.edu\n", "john@yahoo.edu\n", "sally@yahoo.edu\n", "adam@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "myhome@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n", "hunger@yahoo.edu\n", "madison@yahoo.edu\n", ];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = emailList;

//I want to remove the @yahoo.com and then sort the list
function myFunction() {
   var myEmailList = emailList.replace("@yahoo.com", " ");
   myEmailList.sort();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myEmailList;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a for loop to go trough the entire array replacing the current name with one without '@yahoo', then sort it.

Comment: Also, your list of addresses have "@yahoo.edu" not "@yahoo.com", so replacing the latter won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner, people love one-liners

```
var names = emailList.map(function(e){ return e.split('@').shift(); }).sort();
```

If you want to take specifically the `@yahoo*` out, change split param to '@yahoo'

```
 var names = emailList.map(function(e){ return e.split('@yahoo').shift(); }).sort();
```

This will leave non-yahoo addresses untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **map** function to transform your current list to one without the yahoo part.

```
var myEmailList = emailList.map(function(email){
    return email.replace("@yahoo.com", "");
});
```

and then you can sort it.

```
myEmailList.sort();
```

you might also consider joining the list so it looks pretty before putting it back in html.

```
myEmailList.join(","); // joins the elements with a , in between
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each item in the array and replace the string:

```
function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++) {
        emailList[i] = emailList[i].replace("@yahoo.com", "");
    }
    emailList.sort();
}
```

Don't forget to call the function when you need it:

```
myFunction();
```

If you want to append each item in the array onto a DOM element in a `div` tag:

```
function appendToDemo() {
     emailList.map(function(email) {
        document.getElemendById("demo").append(<div>email</div>);
    }
}
```

(or something else to this effect)

Comment: I think you have to set the element `emailList[i]` after the call of replace, like this `emailList[i] = emailList[i].replace("yahoo.com", "");`. Otherwise the list will not be modified.

Comment: @JeanMel, you're correct. I thought it mutated the string instead of returning a new one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a for loop:

```
for (var i in myEmailList) {
    myEmailList[i] = myEmailList[i].replace("@yahoo.com");
}
```

or the map function:

```
myEmailList.map(function(email){return email.replace("@yahoo.com", "");})
```

to get rid of every occurrence of "@yahoo.com" in the strings in the list.

Then, sort the list:

```
myEmailList.sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(replaceString){
 this.join('#').replace(replaceString,'').split('#').sort(); }
emailList.remove('@yahoo.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array methods:

- [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remove the email host
- [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort alphabetically
- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ro remove duplicates

Like this:

```js
var emailList = [ "adam@yahoo.edu\n", "henry@yahoo.edu\n", "john@yahoo.edu\n",
                  "sally@yahoo.edu\n", "adam@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n",
                  "myhome@yahoo.edu\n", "david@yahoo.edu\n","david@yahoo.edu\n",
                  "hunger@yahoo.edu\n", "madison@yahoo.edu\n" ];

emailList = emailList
         .map(function(address){ return address.replace(/@yahoo\.edu\n/,''); })
         .sort(function(a, b){ return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0; })
         .filter(function(address, index, array){ return array.indexOf(address) == index; });

document.write(JSON.stringify(emailList));

// ===  ["adam", "david", "henry", "hunger", "john", "madison", "myhome", "sally"]
```